# Git merge and unstaged files

Tags: git, git-merge

Picture of the situation: you fetch from remote repository and you run a git merge with remote origin having some unstaged files.

How does git merge behave towards unstaged files?

Comment: you should stash or commit them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have `example.md` as an **unstaged** file in your **working directory** and try to merge `origin/remote1` which already tracks `example.md`:

When trying to merge you will get the following error:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    example.md
Please move or remove them before you merge.
Aborting
```

That happens even if the content of the files is identical.

---

**TLDR:** `git merge` **prevents** you from merging if *currently* untracked files in your working directory **could** be overwritten by a merge.

`git` will only **prevent** the merge if local changes **would** be overridden, if the remote did no changes to files you modified locally the merge will finish **without** any problems.

Comment: I have a modified unstaged file in my working directory but merge with origne/remote_branch worked fine. I can't explain.

Comment: How can a `unstaged` file be `modified`? Maybe you had a `tracked modified` file and the merge went well because the file in question was not involved in the merge.

Comment: What does "uninvolved in the merge" mean? If origin/remote1 is tracking example.md and I have a tracked modified (unstaged) example.md, merge would overwrite it, so it shouldn't go.

Comment: uninvolved would mean e.g. `example2.md` is modified, but only `example1.md` is changed on the remote, then the merge should/could (I think) complete without any issues.

Comment: Remote file in fact hasn't changed. So to summarize the error message only comes if remote file has changed since your last commit, otherwise you can merge over unstaged files with no issue.

Comment: Added your findings to my answer

Answer (score 2):

This is all an aside; [AnimiVulpis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46098437/1256452) is fine.  This should be a comment, in other words, but it's much too big to fit as a comment. :-)

---

You need to define a bit more carefully what you mean by "unstaged file".

In Git, there are three important things to keep in your head at all times:

- Which commit is the *current commit*, i.e., what is in `HEAD` right now?  Usually `HEAD` contains the name of a branch, and the branch-name itself contains the hash ID of a commit.  Then that hash ID is the current commit.
- What is in the *index* right now?  The index, also called the *staging area* or sometimes the *cache*, contains what will go into the *next* commit you make.  If you make a new commit right now, whatever is in the index right now becomes the content of that new commit.
- What is in the *work-tree* right now?  The work-tree is the easiest thing to see because it contains all your files, in the normal form your computer has them.  All you have to do is look, and there they are.

The index is a little hard to see, because Git mostly shows it to you by comparing it to the *current commit* and to the *work-tree*.  But normally, initially, it contains all the same files as the current commit, in the special Git-oriented format that makes Git fast.  Once you `git add` a file, though, the index version of that file gets copied from the work-tree version.  Now it matches the work-tree file and not the `HEAD` file.  That's what most documents and people call *staging the file:* copying it from the work-tree into the index.

Some files that are in your work-tree may not be in your index and/or your current commit at all.  In some cases, this is what you *want:* you want the work-tree to hold the compiled code, or the PDF output from a document, or whatever, but you don't want that code to get committed.

A file that is in your work-tree, but not in your index, is *untracked*.  Since it is untracked, it won't be in the next commit.  But `git status` will complain about it: "Hey, this file is untracked!  Did you forget about this file?  Better add this file, right?  Huh?  Track this file now, right?  Pester!  Pester!  Pester!"  To get Git to shut up about this untracked file, you can list it in a `.gitignore` file.  Then Git knows that the untracked file is not meant to be complained-about.  That's most of what `.gitignore` does.  In particular, if a file *is* tracked, adding it to `.gitignore` has no effect at all.  It's only applied to *untracked* files.  Once the file is in the index, you are stuck with it: you have to explicitly *remove* it to take it away.

Since an untracked file is not in the index, some people call this "unstaged" as well.  That's why you have to be careful when talking about "unstaged files": some people consider untracked files "unstaged" too.

---

In any case, `git merge` itself is a bit complicated.  Sometimes it actually merges, and sometimes it does what Git calls a *fast-forward*, which is not really a merge at all.  When Git does a fast-forward instead of a merge, many more things are allowed in terms of what's different in `HEAD`, index, and work-tree.  When Git does a real merge, Git needs to *use* the index to do it, and fewer special cases are allowed.

Comment: I mean a tracked file that has been modified but not staged for the next commit. In [this picture](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/images/lifecycle.png) it's the yellow rectangle, "Modified".

Comment: Right, that would be a file that's modified in the work-tree, and has the index version matching the `HEAD` version. In this case, as long as the merge isn't a real merge (is a "fast forward"), Git really does a `git checkout`, which gets you into [this state](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452).